# Covering from Dense Projection

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, projection, map-projections

Let $V$ be a Banach space, $W$ a (strict) subspace of $V$, and $U$ a dense proper subset of $V$.  When is does there exist a (linear) projection $P^V_W:V\twoheadrightarrow W$, such that
$$
P_W^V(U)=W
.
$$